# How to externalize the log4j.xml file for all appliaction in mule?

Tags: logging, mule, log4j2, mule-studio, anypoint-studio

I want to externalize the log4j.xml file which can be shared by all application, How can it be acheived? Please help.

Answer (score -1):

YOU can save the log4j.XML file in any location by changing the target in the log4j.XML file

so that it can be used by the other application.I think this may help YOU.